# how to change an array to json object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like below

```
let result = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

then need to change like below how to do it Thank you for any help.

```
result  = [
     {
        type: "a",
        image: "a.jpg"
     },
     {
        type: "b",
        image: "b.jpg"
     },
     {
        type: "c",
        image: "c.jpg"
     },
     {
        type: "d",
        image: "d.jpg"
     }
    ]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything in particular that you're having trouble with?

Comment: I alredy try it's work thanks sir. - @Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this.

```
const objResult = result.map((item) => {
  return {
    type: item,
    image: item + '.jpg'
  };
});
```

Comment: C'mon, you can make it way more terse than that ~ `result.map(type => ({ type, image: \`${type}.jpg\` }))` 

Comment: @Direak Yeah, no problem!  If you find this answer useful, you can click that checkmark next to it, to flag your question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to return a new object with `type` & `image` properties like:

```js
let result = ["a","b","c","d"]
result = result.map(r => ({type: r, image: `${r}.jpg`}))
console.log( result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) Array methods achieve the result:

```js
let obj = [];
let result = ["a","b","c","d"]

result.forEach(function(el, i) {
  obj.push({
    type: el,
    image: `${el}.jpg`
  }) 
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would describe your function like this -

```
function convertResult(result){
    let ans = [];
    for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
        ans[i] = {'type': result[i], 'image': result[i]+'.jpg'};
    }
    return ans;
}
```

then you would call your function as this -

```
let result = ["a","b","c","d"]
let ans = convertResult(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use map

```js
let result = ["a","b","c","d"]
const map = result.map(x => ({"type":x,"image": x+".jpg"}));
console.log(map);
```